# R paste data frame rows that belong to same id

Tags: r, paste

I am trying to paste together text data from the same user that is currently organized in different rows by name:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 'name text
"katy" "tomorrow I go"
"lauren" "and computing"
"katy" "to the store"
"stephanie" "foo and foos"')
```

to have a result of:

```
df2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='name text
"katy" "tomorrow I go to the store"
"lauren" "and computing"
"stephanie" "foo and foos"')
```

suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use either `data.table` or `dplyr` or `aggregate` to `paste` the 'text' column grouped by 'name'.  With `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), before doing this.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(text=paste(text, collapse=' ')), by = name]
```

---

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   summarise(text=paste(text, collapse=' '))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
aggregate(text~name, df, FUN= paste, collapse=' ')
```

Comment: If you want to group by two columns (Name and other different as Text) and one of these columns have NAs, `aggregate` won't take care of the NAs! However, the solution with dplyr works perfectly. Example: 
`EnsemblID <- c("ENSG00000138594", "ENSG00000138594", "ENSG00000138594", "ENSG00000253251", "ENSG00000001629", "ENSG00000001629", "ENSG00000001629", "ENSG00000001629", "ENSG00000005513", "ENSG00000186448")
EntrezIDs <- c(112268148, 112268148, 112268148, 112441434, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 110354863)
`

Comment: `GO_function <- c("GO:0003779", "GO:0005523", "GO:0098641", "GO:0005515", "GO:0004842", "GO:0004843", "GO:0004844", "GO:0004845", "GO:0016740", "GO:0016743")`
`data <- data.frame(EnsemblID, EntrezIDs, GO_function)`
`data_collapsed = aggregate(data=data, GO_function~., FUN=paste, collapse=", ") # we don't have NAs`
`data_collapsed3 = data %>%
  group_by(EnsemblID, EntrezIDs) %>%
  summarise(GO_function=paste(GO_function, collapse=',')) # we keep the NAs`

Comment: @emr2 `aggregate`, you have to use `na.action = NULL` with `function(x) paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = " ")`

Comment: Like this?  `aggregate(data=data, GO_function~., na.action = NULL,  function(x) paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = " "))` ? I still lose the NAs.

Comment: @emr2 the NAs are in the group columns.  Perhaps you can convert to character `aggregate(data=replace(data, is.na(data), "NA"), GO_function~., na.action = NULL,  function(x) paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = " "))`